# Problemas con las consultas correlacionadas en BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Estoy intentando obtener de una tabla de llamadas telefónicas, para cada día el número de teléfonos únicos que han llamado en los últimos 30 días. Más exactamente, lo que quiero obtener es para cada día, el total de números de teléfono que llamaron ése día y que **NO** hayan llamado en los últimos 30 días. He intentado hacer una consulta correlacionada, pero siempre que en Bigquery realizo alguna consulta correlacionada me sale el error

> "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an
> equality of fields from both sides of the join."

Esta es la consulta que he probado:

```
select fecha, count(l.phone) as leadsDelio
  from(SELECT distinct (cast(cast(fecha_de_alta as timestamp) as date)) as fecha, phone
  FROM `tablaLlamadas` E
  where phone not in
  (select distinct phone
  from `tablaLlamadas`
  where (cast(cast(fecha_de_alta as timestamp) as date)) between date(cast(DATE_ADD(date(cast(DATE_ADD(date(E.fecha_de_alta), INTERVAL -1 DAY) as timestamp)), INTERVAL -30 DAY) as timestamp))
  and date(cast(DATE_ADD(date(E.fecha_de_alta), INTERVAL -1 DAY) as timestamp)))) l
  group by fecha;
```

Como he mencionado, esta consulta me devuelve el error del `LEFT JOIN`. Buscando otras soluciones, he leído que se puede utilizar un `CROSS JOIN` para salvar ése error, pero no me funciona porque llego al tope de recursos

> "Query exceeded resource limits. 32315.79583176217 CPU seconds were
> used, and this query must use less than 2500.0 CPU seconds."

Esta es la consulta con el cross join:

```
select fecha, count(phone) as leadsDelio
from(SELECT distinct (cast(cast(E1.fecha_de_alta as timestamp) as date)) as fecha, E1.phone as phone
FROM `tablaLlamadas` E1
cross join `tablaLlamadas` E2
where (cast(cast(E2.fecha_de_alta as timestamp) as date)) between date(cast(DATE_ADD(date(cast(DATE_ADD(date(E1.fecha_de_alta), INTERVAL -1 DAY) as timestamp)), INTERVAL -30 DAY) as timestamp))
  and date(cast(DATE_ADD(date(E1.fecha_de_alta), INTERVAL -1 DAY) as timestamp)))
  group by fecha;
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda con respecto a este tema.

Answer (score 0):

Otra alternativa seria:

Considerando que se desea obtener el numero de total de teléfonos de la fecha "2020-09-27” a la fecha "2020-09-29".

1. Obtener los resultados entre la fecha inicial ("2020-09-27”) menos 30 días y la fecha final ("2020-09-29”) agrupados por fecha y teléfono

```
SELECT
  telefono,
  fecha
FROM
  `tu_tabla`
WHERE
  fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE "2020-09-27", INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  AND DATE("2020-09-29")
GROUP BY
  telefono,
  fecha
```

2. Ahora como paso intermedio solo como prueba podemos traer los teléfonos que llamaron el día "2020-09-27” y que no  tengan registros de llamadas 30 días atrás

```
WITH
  telefonosPorFecha AS ( //Consulta del primer paso )
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      telefonosPorFecha
    WHERE
      fecha = "2020-09-27") AS tablaObjetivo
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      telefono AS telefonoHistorial
    FROM
      telefonosPorFecha
    WHERE
      fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB("2020-09-27", INTERVAL 30 DAY)
      AND DATE_SUB("2020-09-27", INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS tablaHistorico
  ON
    tablaObjetivo.telefono = tablaHistorico.telefonoHistorial)
WHERE
  telefonoHistorial IS NULL;
```

3. Detectando los teléfonos únicos ahora seria aplicarlo no a una fecha en concreto sino a un rango y hacer el conteo de teléfonos

```
WITH
  telefonosPorFecha AS ( //Consulta del primer paso )
SELECT
  fechaAConsultar AS fecha,
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT *
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT *
      FROM (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          telefonosPorFecha
        WHERE
          fecha = fechaAConsultar) AS tablaObjetivo
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
          telefono AS telefonoHistorial
        FROM
          telefonosPorFecha
        WHERE
          fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB(fechaAConsultar, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          AND DATE_SUB(fechaAConsultar, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS tablaHistorico
      ON
        tablaObjetivo.telefono = tablaHistorico.telefonoHistorial)
    WHERE
      telefonoHistorial IS NULL)) AS numeroDeTelefonos
FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2020-09-27", "2020-09-29")) AS fechaAConsultar
```

Dejo una consulta completa para pruebas

```
WITH
  telefonosPorFecha AS (
  SELECT
    telefono,
    fecha
  FROM (
    SELECT
      "1234567890" AS telefono,
      DATE("2020-09-29") AS fecha
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567885",
      "2020-09-29"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567886",
      "2020-09-29"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567898",
      "2020-09-29"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567882",
      "2020-09-28"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567886",
      "2020-09-28"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567893",
      "2020-09-27"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567894",
      "2020-09-27"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567894",
      "2020-09-27"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567897",
      "2020-09-27"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567891",
      "2020-09-25"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567899",
      "2020-09-23"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567895",
      "2020-09-22"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567895",
      "2020-09-21"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567897",
      "2020-09-03"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567894",
      "2020-09-01"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567891",
      "2020-08-29"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567899",
      "2020-08-26"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567892",
      "2020-08-25"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      "1234567891",
      "2020-08-22" )
  WHERE
    fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE "2020-09-27", INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    AND DATE("2020-09-29")
  GROUP BY
    telefono,
    fecha )
SELECT
  fechaAConsultar AS fecha,
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT *
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT *
      FROM (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          telefonosPorFecha
        WHERE
          fecha = fechaAConsultar) AS tablaObjetivo
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
          telefono AS telefonoHistorial
        FROM
          telefonosPorFecha
        WHERE
          fecha BETWEEN DATE_SUB(fechaAConsultar, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
          AND DATE_SUB(fechaAConsultar, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS tablaHistorico
      ON
        tablaObjetivo.telefono = tablaHistorico.telefonoHistorial)
    WHERE
      telefonoHistorial IS NULL)) AS numeroDeTelefonos
FROM
  UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY("2020-09-27", "2020-09-29")) AS fechaAConsultar;
```